# How to solve recurrences with big-O instead of big theta?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, recurrence

I'm looking at the following problem:
`T(n)=57*T(n/4) + O(n^3)`
I understand that I need to use the master theorem to solve this, but all the examples in my textbook and online have big theta in the equation instead of big-O. Are the three cases the same for both?
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You are given a family of recurrences. The conclusions that you will be able to obtain are different depending on the actual function taken from O(n^3). So, you will need to split the analysis in cases. Observe that c=log_4(57) < 3. This means that O(n^c) is a proper subset of O(n^3). So, for those elements of O(n^3) that are also in some O(n^r) with r< c, you will be able to say that T is in Theta(n^c). For elements of O(n^3) that are also in some Theta(n^c*log^k n) you will be able to say that T is in Theta(n^clog^{k+1}n). For some elements of O(n^3) you won't be able to say much.

Comment: By the way, none of this is 'solving the recurrence'. The Master Theorem doesn't solve recurrences. It is rather bounding, or finding asymptotics, of its solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Theta is good enough for your purpose:

[image]

Comment: This statement is true but not useful here. The given recurrence uses big-O notation, which means that it’s not possible to determine the exact order of growth of the last term of the recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. These two are not the same:

```
T(n) = 57*T(n/4) + O(n^3)
T(n) = 57*T(n/4) + \Theta(n^3)
```

However, you can use the master theorem to reach some `big-O` analysis for `T(n)`. Hence, using the second case to analyze `T(n)`, and using `O` instead of `Theta` in the final result as if `f(n) = Theta(g(n))` you can say `f(n) = O(g(n))` too!

Comment: The theorem should not be used, since its hypotheses are not satisfied. Rather, use the technique used in its proof adapted to the family of recurrences in this case.